# NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages

Tags: imap, aol

I'm using AfterLogic MailBee for downloading AOL messages via `IMAP`

I keep on getting error messages again and again, for years. I would like to solve this once and for all.

Here's a sample log. I can post a much longer one if necessary.

```
[13:04:57.83] [RECV]  BODY[TEXT]<0> {71249}\r\n
[13:04:57.84] [RECV] --===============5885760849945711156==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain ... \r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n--===============5885760849945711156==--\r\n [Literal of length 71249.]
[13:04:57.86] [RECV] )\r\n [Total 79854 bytes received.]
[13:04:57.88] [RECV] MBN00000005 OK UID FETCH completed\r\n [Total 36 bytes received.]
[13:04:57.89] [INFO] Envelopes downloaded
[13:04:58.07] [INFO] Will download envelopes.
[13:04:58.08] [SEND] MBN00000006 UID FETCH 50971 (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.2147483647>)\r\n

ERROR ON NEXT LINE:

[13:05:28.27] [RECV] MBN00000006 NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages\r\n [Total 77 bytes received.]
[13:05:28.29] [INFO] Error: The server has responded with negative reply. The server responded: MBN00000006 NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages.
[13:05:38.45] [INFO] Assembly version: 11.2.0 build 590 for .NET 4.5.
[13:05:38.45] [INFO] Will download list of sub-folders of "" folder matching "" condition.
[13:05:38.47] [SEND] MBN00000002 LIST "" "*"\r\n
```

I would like to point out that it's not consistent. It comes and goes. But it definitely happens a lot, just that in the end usually all emails come in.

Any help/ideas/pointers are most welcome
Thanks!

**UPDATE - Log #2**

Hi

Here's a fuller log. i truncate the huge uid list, for readability. also i replaced some private data such as emails etc with "AAAAA"
otherwise untouched

The error is at the end

Thanks again!

```
[12:50:06.74] [INFO] Assembly version: 11.2.0 build 590 for .NET 4.5.
[12:50:06.74] [INFO] Will download list of sub-folders of "" folder matching "" condition.
[12:50:06.77] [SEND] MBN00000002 LIST "" "*"\r\n
[12:50:07.31] [RECV] * LIST (\Archive \HasNoChildren) "/" "Archive"\r\n [Total 48 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.48] [RECV] * LIST (\Junk \HasNoChildren) "/" "Bulk Mail"\r\n [Total 47 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.49] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"\r\n [Total 45 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.49] [RECV] * LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "Draft"\r\n [Total 45 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.49] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Inbox"\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.50] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"\r\n [Total 43 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.50] [RECV] * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Saved"\r\n [Total 35 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.51] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Saved/SavedIMs"\r\n [Total 46 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.51] [RECV] * LIST (\Sent \HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.52] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.52] [RECV] * LIST (\Trash \HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"\r\n [Total 44 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.52] [RECV] MBN00000002 OK LIST completed\r\n [Total 31 bytes received.]
[12:50:07.53] [INFO] Folder list downloaded.
[12:50:09.03] [INFO] Select folder "Archive".
[12:50:09.04] [SEND] MBN00000003 EXAMINE "Archive"\r\n
[12:50:09.55] [RECV] * 0 EXISTS\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.70] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.71] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1516594547] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.73] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 60001] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.75] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.77] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.78] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1]\r\n [Total 24 bytes received.]
[12:50:09.80] [RECV] MBN00000003 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:10.30] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:10.30] [SEND] MBN00000004 UID SEARCH UID 1:*\r\n
[12:50:10.84] [RECV] * SEARCH \r\n [Total 11 bytes received.]
[12:50:10.90] [RECV] MBN00000004 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:10.91] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:11.41] [INFO] Select folder "Draft".
[12:50:11.43] [SEND] MBN00000005 EXAMINE "Draft"\r\n
[12:50:11.96] [RECV] * 0 EXISTS\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.00] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.01] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1516594546] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.01] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 60083] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.02] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.02] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.02] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 165]\r\n [Total 26 bytes received.]
[12:50:12.03] [RECV] MBN00000005 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:14.67] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:14.68] [SEND] MBN00000006 UID SEARCH UID 1:*\r\n
[12:50:15.16] [RECV] * SEARCH \r\n [Total 11 bytes received.]
[12:50:15.21] [RECV] MBN00000006 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:15.22] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:18.40] [INFO] Select folder "Inbox".
[12:50:18.41] [SEND] MBN00000007 EXAMINE "Inbox"\r\n
[12:50:18.64] [RECV] * 29581 EXISTS\r\n [Total 16 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.78] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.79] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1516594546] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.79] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 102412] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.80] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.80] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.81] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 116489]\r\n [Total 29 bytes received.]
[12:50:18.81] [RECV] MBN00000007 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:20.28] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:20.28] [SEND] MBN00000008 UID SEARCH UID 26614728:*\r\n
[12:50:20.53] [RECV] * SEARCH 102411 \r\n [Total 18 bytes received.]
[12:50:20.57] [RECV] MBN00000008 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:20.58] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:21.12] [INFO] Select folder "Saved".
[12:50:21.37] [SEND] MBN00000009 EXAMINE "Saved"\r\n
[12:50:21.76] [RECV] * 2 EXISTS\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.80] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.81] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1518399361] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.81] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 60003] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.82] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.82] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.83] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 6]\r\n [Total 24 bytes received.]
[12:50:21.83] [RECV] MBN00000009 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.11] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:22.12] [SEND] MBN00000010 UID SEARCH UID 26100440:*\r\n
[12:50:22.39] [RECV] * SEARCH 20002 \r\n [Total 17 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.44] [RECV] MBN00000010 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.44] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:22.62] [INFO] Select folder "Saved/SavedIMs".
[12:50:22.63] [SEND] MBN00000011 EXAMINE "Saved/SavedIMs"\r\n
[12:50:22.91] [RECV] * 0 EXISTS\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.91] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.92] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1518399361] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.92] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 60001] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.93] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.93] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.94] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1]\r\n [Total 24 bytes received.]
[12:50:22.95] [RECV] MBN00000011 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:23.20] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:23.21] [SEND] MBN00000012 UID SEARCH UID 1:*\r\n
[12:50:23.56] [RECV] * SEARCH \r\n [Total 11 bytes received.]
[12:50:23.61] [RECV] MBN00000012 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:23.62] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:23.91] [INFO] Select folder "Sent".
[12:50:23.91] [SEND] MBN00000013 EXAMINE "Sent"\r\n
[12:50:24.22] [RECV] * 8299 EXISTS\r\n [Total 15 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.27] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.27] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1516594546] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.28] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 68846] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.28] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.28] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.29] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 17501]\r\n [Total 28 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.29] [RECV] MBN00000013 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:24.72] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:24.91] [SEND] MBN00000014 UID SEARCH UID 26614726:*\r\n
[12:50:25.20] [RECV] * SEARCH 68845 \r\n [Total 17 bytes received.]
[12:50:25.41] [RECV] MBN00000014 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:25.42] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:25.72] [INFO] Select folder "Sent Items".
[12:50:25.73] [SEND] MBN00000015 EXAMINE "Sent Items"\r\n
[12:50:26.11] [RECV] * 0 EXISTS\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.15] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.16] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1518399361] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.16] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 60001] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 41 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.16] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.17] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.17] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1]\r\n [Total 24 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.18] [RECV] MBN00000015 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:26.87] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:26.88] [SEND] MBN00000016 UID SEARCH UID 1:*\r\n
[12:50:27.13] [RECV] * SEARCH \r\n [Total 11 bytes received.]
[12:50:27.25] [RECV] MBN00000016 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:27.25] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:47.78] [INFO] Assembly version: 11.2.0 build 590 for .NET 4.5.
[12:50:47.78] [INFO] Will download list of sub-folders of "" folder matching "" condition.
[12:50:47.79] [SEND] MBN00000002 LIST "" "*"\r\n
[12:50:48.31] [RECV] * LIST (\Archive \HasNoChildren) "/" "Archive"\r\n [Total 48 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.31] [RECV] * LIST (\Junk \HasNoChildren) "/" "Bulk Mail"\r\n [Total 47 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.32] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"\r\n [Total 45 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.33] [RECV] * LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "Draft"\r\n [Total 45 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.34] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Inbox"\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.35] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"\r\n [Total 43 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.35] [RECV] * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Saved"\r\n [Total 35 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.36] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Saved/SavedIMs"\r\n [Total 46 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.36] [RECV] * LIST (\Sent \HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.37] [RECV] * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.37] [RECV] * LIST (\Trash \HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"\r\n [Total 44 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.38] [RECV] MBN00000002 OK LIST completed\r\n [Total 31 bytes received.]
[12:50:48.38] [INFO] Folder list downloaded.
[12:50:50.63] [INFO] Select folder "Inbox".
[12:50:50.64] [SEND] MBN00000003 EXAMINE "Inbox"\r\n
[12:50:51.17] [RECV] * 29581 EXISTS\r\n [Total 16 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.21] [RECV] * 0 RECENT\r\n [Total 12 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.22] [RECV] * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1516594546] UIDs valid\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.23] [RECV] * OK [UIDNEXT 102412] Predicted next UID\r\n [Total 42 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.23] [RECV] * FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk)\r\n [Total 78 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.24] [RECV] * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] No permanent flags permitted\r\n [Total 55 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.24] [RECV] * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 116489]\r\n [Total 29 bytes received.]
[12:50:51.25] [RECV] MBN00000003 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed; now in selected state\r\n [Total 69 bytes received.]
[12:50:53.51] [INFO] Will perform search in the folder.
[12:50:53.51] [SEND] MBN00000004 UID SEARCH ALL\r\n
[12:50:56.29] [RECV] * SEARCH 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 23 24 25 28 29 30 31 32 33 35 37 39 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 88 89 90 91 94 95 96 97 98 99 101 102 103 104 105 106 ........  50941 50942 50943 50944 50945 50946 50948 50950 50951 50952 50953 50954 50956 50957 50958 50959 50960 50961 50962 50963 50964 50965 50966 50967 50968 50969 50970 50971 50972 50973 50974 50975 50976 50977 50978 50979 50980 50981 50982 50983 50984 50985 50986 50987 50988 50989 50990 50991 50992 50993 50994 50995 50996  .......   102373 102374 102375 102376 102377 102378 102379 102380 102381 102382 102383 102384 102385 102386 102387 102388 102389 102390 102391 102392 102393 102394 102395 102396 102397 102398 102399 102400 102401 102402 102403 102404 102405 102406 102407 102408 102409 102410 102411 \r\n [Total 168437 bytes received.]
[12:50:56.30] [RECV] MBN00000004 OK UID SEARCH completed\r\n [Total 37 bytes received.]
[12:50:56.32] [INFO] Search done.
[12:50:56.34] [INFO] Will download envelopes.
[12:50:56.34] [SEND] MBN00000005 UID FETCH 50946 (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.2147483647>)\r\n
[12:50:57.45] [RECV] * 19977 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen) UID 50946 INTERNALDATE "16-Oct-2018 17:00:37 +0000" RFC822.SIZE 79046 BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 11625 191 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("text" "html" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 59281 1080 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "alternative" ("boundary" "===============5885760849945711156==") NIL) ENVELOPE ("Tue, 16 Oct 2018 17:00:36 +0000 (UTC)" "$139.99 Dell i5 Quad Core PC" (("AAAAA" NIL "officesale" "AAAAA.com")) (("AAAAA" NIL "officesale" "AAAAA.com")) (("AAAAA" NIL "officesale" "AAAAA.com")) (("AAAAA" NIL "AAAAA" "aol.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<5IhE0ItQTeOlCUsfbIJlPA@ismtpd0049p1mdw1.AAAAA.net>") BODY[HEADER] {7820}\r\n
[12:50:57.45] [RECV] Return-Path: <bounces+6830976-236e-AAAAA=aol.com@send.ksd2.klav ...  send.ksd2.AAAAA.com SPF : pass\r\nContent-Length: 69965\r\n\r\n [Literal of length 7820.]
[12:50:57.46] [RECV]  BODY[TEXT]<0> {71249}\r\n
[12:50:57.46] [RECV] --===============5885760849945711156==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain ... \r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n--===============5885760849945711156==--\r\n [Literal of length 71249.]
[12:50:57.47] [RECV] )\r\n [Total 79854 bytes received.]
[12:50:57.58] [RECV] MBN00000005 OK UID FETCH completed\r\n [Total 36 bytes received.]
[12:50:57.59] [INFO] Envelopes downloaded
[12:50:58.03] [INFO] Will download envelopes.
[12:50:58.04] [SEND] MBN00000006 UID FETCH 50971 (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.2147483647>)\r\n
[12:51:28.51] [RECV] MBN00000006 NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages\r\n [Total 77 bytes received.]
[12:51:28.53] [INFO] Error: The server has responded with negative reply. The server responded: MBN00000006 NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages.
```

Comment: How do you know that UID 50971 is valid for the current folder? More logs can be helpful.

Comment: These are bugs with AOL's server.  It either has transient outages (eg, can't reach the database server), or it can't parse the message and returns a NO.  You'll have to work around it or ignore the message.

Comment: @Alex, I'll have to try to get the error again, meanwhile its not falling. as soon as it happens again (probably within a few days or so) ill try to post more complete logs. thanks so much meanwhile!

Comment: @Alex, Thanks. I've added a complete log now. Please advise.

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski Thanks. However, the updated log still suffers the same problem. It never mentions 50971 UID. In the log you're requesting it but there is no indication that it's valid for this mailbox as there is no server response which would contain this UID anywhere (e.g. in search results).

Comment: @Alex, Thanks to you :-). I had truncated for readability. I now added a few more uids, including 50971. (the real list is thousands long...)

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski Thanks. So, it's indeed AOL server problem. You can try to experiment with downloading the problematic message in alternative ways. For instance, download just its envelope. Or just body structure. Or just message header. And so on. To find what exactly causes the problem. From that, maybe it will be possible to invent some workaround.

Comment: @Alex The issue is actually by downloading the envelope. If it's an AOL issue, how come it happens again and again on this same message?  Also, I now realize that another client which uses identical code, has in the past downloaded this message. Can a message become corrupted out of the blue?

Comment: You're actually downloading much more than ENVELOPE. Try to narrow it down. Request just ENVELOPE, for instance, and not the whole UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.2147483647> data set.

Comment: Hi. If i try only bodystructure then yes, it works, but i dont get anything. what can be the issue with this specific message?

Comment: Probably. You may also try to download it via POP3. Maybe it's only IMAP that it causing issues with it.

Comment: i dont have the users pop3 creds. also i wouldnt want to have 2 parallel message downloaders. id rather solve this with imap. what can the matter be?

Comment: Why should POP3 creds be different? But you can keep experimenting with IMAP, if you wish, trying to find the combination of the items to fetch which wouldn't trigger the error in AOL server. For instance, request just message body and no bodystructure, envelope, etc. Instead BODY.PEEK[0.xx] do normal download of an entire email. I.e. try Imap.DownloadEntireMessage method in MailBee.